# Ubuntu Server can not connect ssh from outside

Tags: networking, ssh, server, ubuntu-server

We have ubuntu server installed on our desktop machine. It is connected modem with ethernet port. We can access it with ssh via inside of our network. But can not from outside.

Here is what we've done so far:

- We have static ip
- My professor made this i dont know what it is
  [image]
- Our ubuntu server machine always picks `192.168.1.200`
  [image]
- We have port forwarding
  [image]

when I run `ssh maviarge@213.XXXXXXX` from our LAN which holds ubuntu server machine

```
maviarge@213.XXXXXXX's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-104-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Thu 10 Mar 2022 08:45:36 AM UTC

  System load:  0.07               Processes:                166
  Usage of /:   2.0% of 438.13GB   Users logged in:          1
  Memory usage: 2%                 IPv4 address for docker0: 172.17.0.1
  Swap usage:   0%                 IPv4 address for enp3s0:  192.168.1.200
  Temperature:  50.0 C

 * Super-optimized for small spaces - read how we shrank the memory
   footprint of MicroK8s to make it the smallest full K8s around.

   https://ubuntu.com/blog/microk8s-memory-optimisation

0 updates can be applied immediately.
```

But when I run `ssh -v maviarge@213.XXXXXXX` from outside of our wifi.

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\MaviArge/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to 213.XXXXXXX [213.XXXXXXX] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 213.XXXXXXX port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 213.XXXXXXX port 22: Connection timed out
```

When I run `ping 213.XXXXXXX`  from outside

```
Pinging 213.XXXXXXX with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 213.XXXXXXX: bytes=32 time=67ms TTL=46
Reply from 213.XXXXXXX: bytes=32 time=97ms TTL=46
Reply from 213.XXXXXXX: bytes=32 time=107ms TTL=46
Reply from 213.XXXXXXX: bytes=32 time=124ms TTL=46

Ping statistics for 213.XXXXXXX:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 67ms, Maximum = 124ms, Average = 98ms
```

Saw this command on internet `sudo lsof -i:22` and the output:

```
sudo lsof -i:22
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    3290     root    4u  IPv4  38814      0t0  TCP maviarge:ssh->host-213.XXXXXXX.reverse.superonline.net:58124 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    3375 maviarge    4u  IPv4  38814      0t0  TCP maviarge:ssh->host-213.XXXXXXX.reverse.superonline.net:58124 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    4057     root    3u  IPv4  71589      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    4057     root    4u  IPv6  71591      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    5662     root    4u  IPv4  74261      0t0  TCP maviarge:ssh->host-213.XXXXXXX.reverse.superonline.net:60472 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    5746 maviarge    4u  IPv4  74261      0t0  TCP maviarge:ssh->host-213.XXXXXXX.reverse.superonline.net:60472 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Also nmap scan:

```
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-03-10 05:17 EST
Nmap scan report for host-213.XXXXXXX.reverse.superonline.net (213.XXXXXXX)
Host is up (0.14s latency).
Not shown: 96 closed tcp ports (reset)
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   filtered ssh
25/tcp   filtered smtp
5060/tcp filtered sip
5432/tcp open     postgresql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.08 seconds
```

What's wrong?

Comment: you need to check port forward working correctly

Comment: @muhammadshahan how can i do?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/968641/setting-up-server-to-connect-using-ssh-over-the-internet-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

have you try this

```
sudo ufw allow from any to any port 22 proto tcp
```

or

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```